# CLion IDE: Use ssh as an environnent toolchains instead of MinGW/Cygwin on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ssh, clion

I'm currently using CLion 2016.2 and I would to use ssh as an environment toolchains instead of MinGW/Cygwin on Windows. For instance, Pycharm already support remote location for an environment [using a ssh location](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html)(or using a docker container) and it works well. I would like to known if such feature could possible with CLion or maybe on a later version?

So far, I see there's difference when trying to configure CLion Toolchains on Windows or Linux:

[image: Clion Screenshot for Windows]
(The Windows Clion Toolchains Settings)

[image: Clion Screenshot for Ubuntu]
(The Ubuntu Clion Toolchains Settings)

Yet, I don't see anything about remote location such as ssh or docker to configure the environment, which would be particularly useful for Windows.

Comment: Good news, they're working on it!  https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/09/initial-remote-dev-support-clion/  Bad news:  It only syncs one way right now (client->server) and I haven't seen anything regarding Docker support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CLion2018.3 or above you can do it:

[image]

See:

https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html

for more information.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with CLion now. And probably this won't come in the nearest updates. Some related feature request you could follow is about Ubuntu toolchain on Windows: [CPP-6352](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6352)